# Regex of dynamic block of characters

Tags: regex

I have a block of number characters separated by '=' and the number range can be always different on both sides.
Example: `12345678999999=654784651321`, next time it could be: `4567894135=456789211`

I need help with finding suitable regex which select me always numbers between first 6 and last 4 digits of left side of block and then all numbers after 7th digit of right side of block:

```
123456[][][][]9999=6547846[][][][][]
```

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: What have you tried? Because this seems trivial. You've got 6 parts: 6 digits, some more digits, 4 digits, =, 7 digits, some more digits.

Comment: `^\d{6}(?<first>.+?)\d{4}=\d{7}(?<second>.+)$` (the most significant part is using the lazy quantifier `+?` but not strictly needed because anyway we are assuming the string contains the expression only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[0-9]{6}([0-9]*)[0-9]{4}=[0-9]{7}([0-9]*)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the difficulty isn't matching a continuous set of digits, but rather matches each digit seperately try:

```
(?:^\d{6}|=\d{7}|\G)(?=\d{5,8}=|\d*$)\K\d
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/0OAP8X/1)

- `(?:` - Open non-capture group for alternation;

  - `^\d{6}` - Match start-line anchor followed by 6 digits;
  - `|` - Or;
  - `=\d{7}` - Match a literal '=' followed by exactly 7 digits;
  - `|` - Or;
  - `\G` - Assert position at end of previous match or start of string;
- `(?=\d{5,8}=|\d*$)` - Positive lookahead to assert possition is followed by either 5-8 digits upto an '=' ***or*** 0+ (greedy) digits upto end-line anchor;
- `\K` - Reset starting point of previous reported match;
- `\d` - A single digit.

---

Alternatively, if you have an environment that supports zero-width lookbehind like JavaScript or PyPi's regex package in Python, try:

```
(?:(?=\d{5,8}=)(?<=\d{6})|(?<==\d{7,}))\d
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4h1tBJ/1)

- `(?:` - Open non-capture group for alternation;

  - `(?=\d{5,8}=)(?<=\d{6})` - Positive lookahead to assert position is followed by 5-8 digits and an '=' but also preceded by at least 6 digits;
  - `|` - Or;
  - `(?<==\d{7,})` - Positive lookbehind to assert position is preceded by an '=' followed by 7+ digits;
- `\d` - A single digit.

Answer (score 0):

```
//    6   NOT number or =      
//    ||                     
//    \/                 
/[0-9]{6}[^\=0-9]*\=[^\=0-9]*[0-9]{4}/
```